# Java restful post - error 400

Tags: java, rest, post, java-8, restful

estoy empezando con restful en java y al momento de hacer POST en mi ejemplo me sale lo siguiente

> Tipo Informe de estado
>
> mensaje Method Not Allowed
>
> Descripción El método HTTP especificado no está permitido para el
> recurso requerido.

No entiendo porqué me sale ese error cuando en postman le envío un JSON, adjunto mi código en java y lo que estoy poniendo en postman

```
public class Model {
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
    private double precio;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
```

Mi GenericResource

@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

```
@Context
private UriInfo context;

public GenericResource() {
}

static final List<Model> lista = new ArrayList<>();

@GET
@Path("listar")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Model> listarProductos(){
    return lista;
}

@POST
@Path("guardar")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public List<Model> guardar(Model m){
    lista.add(m);
    return lista;
}
```

}

Lo que sale en postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En GenericResource en el metodo guardar pides por parametro un tipo Model, pero en postman estas pasando una lista ( entre [] ).